# How to merge togheter Angular frontend with NestJS backend

Tags: angular, nestjs, mean-stack

I'm following a tutorial on **Sololearn** on how to create an application with **NestJS** and **Angular** and it says that i need to run **Angular** server and **NestJS** server separately, is there a way to run them in the same server? I used to code in **PHP** and there you have different routes and you sand back the HTML pages based on them but now I have a single page that changes based on the url. So, after all of this the question still the same: **Is there a way to run Angular and NestJS as the same server?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short answer: **yes**. 
To do that: 
*frontend (angular):*

- change the URL of the API in your angular project to `/api`
- build your angular project `ng build // or ng build --prod // for     poduction`

*backend (Nestjs):*

- install `npm install --save @nestjs/serve-static` to serve static files
- move the angular build output `dist` folder to the nestjs project with a different name like for example `frontend`
- import the `ServerStaticModule` to the `Appmodule`

  ```
      imports: [
      ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
        rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'frontend'),
      }),
    ],
  ```

then you can access your website  from http://localhost:port

for more details :

[Server Static nestjs doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static)

[Use nest as your server-side application with an Angular frontend](https://medium.com/@bo.vandersteene/use-nest-as-your-server-side-application-with-an-angular-frontend-540b0365bfa3)

Answer (score 0):

You can run them on the same "physical" server.
But they need to get started seperatley (for dev purpose) ng serve for angular and nest start for the nest backend.

There is absolutely no need to do them on different "physical" servers :).

Comment: I didn't mean of starting them on two different physical servers but to run the two servers (ng serve, nest start) as one like just using "nest start"

Comment: Ah ok, you can Use Nest as your webserver if you really wanted to (wouldnt encourage it)
for example with something like this
`
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Get()
  root(@Res() response): void {
    // the homepage will load our index.html which contains angular logic
    response.sendFile(path.resolve('../dist/index.html'));
  }
`

the index.html is the one angular generated for you after you did ng build.

https://medium.com/@bo.vandersteene/use-nest-as-your-server-side-application-with-an-angular-frontend-540b0365bfa3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run both Angular and NestJS on the same server.
One approach, although not required is to run each in a docker container.

I have integrated Angular and NestJS in a boilerplate project.
You can refer to the "prod" folder there and check the docker compose file.
Feel free to fork the project and use it as a base for your own.

https://github.com/godardth/typescript-fullstack-boilerplate